# Non-planar graphs with chromatic number less than 5?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

Is it true that nonplanar graphs whose chromatic numbers are less than 5 are almost bipartite?

The reason I raise this question is that in this case, the nonplanarity should come from a minor of $K_{3,3}$ since they cannot have a $K_5$ (am I right?)

So it must be almost bipartite with some additional edges, which means that it should have a big max-cut.

Are there some results concerning this?

Comment: You certainly can have a $K_5.$ think of one with edges subdivided.

Comment: By Brook's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks'_theorem) almost every graph with degree $\leq 5$ has chromatic number $\leq 5$. So, definitely no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what "almost" bipartite means here, but it seems that you can make examples that are quite far from being bipartite.

For example let you graph has node set $\{1,2,3,4\}\times\{1,2,\ldots n\}$ for a sufficiently large $n$, and edges between any two nodes with different *first* components. This has chromatic number $4$ and is non-planar (since it has $K_5$ as a minor) for $n\ge 2$

Comment: Why it has $K_5$ as a minor? As I know for finding a minor you must partition your graph to stable sets and join to sets iff there is an edge between those edges.

Comment: @Bellmondo: $K_5$ is the minor resulting for the partitioning into $\{(1,1)\}, \{(2,1)\}, \{(3,1)\}, \{(4,1)\}$, and then everything else.

Comment: Everything else is not a stable set!

Comment: @Bellmondo: It doesn't have to be (or if it does, your concept of a graph minor is quite nonstandard).

Comment: But if it does not $C_n$ is nonPlanar too! Consider a large enough n and partition it to five random parts. With high probability these part have edge between hence it would be a $K_5$ minor

Comment: @Bellmondo: Very confused now. Exactly what does a "stable set" mean to you here? The sets in the partition have to be _connected_, but "everything else" _is_ connected.

Comment: Oops! That's it. I confused the definition of minor! Thanks & apology.